# Kibana: CONTROL visualization doesn’t show all values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to use a CONTROL visualization of a string field. But the drop down list doesn't show all possible values.
I have no other filters such as time to limit the range of values. Please see the following link for an example
[CONTROL visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKhik.png)

What can I do so that all values are shown?

PS I use kibana 7.7

Thank you, elisavet!

Comment: if you start typing you'll see more options related to what you're typing

Comment: looking at the screen you shared there is the scroll on the right hand side of the box which will allow you to scroll and see all the values. It is very small in the image may be because you have large number of values for that field in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @Val you are right, but the field has 160 values and more likely users don't know beforehand  what to type. Any idea how to state to kibana 'bring me more values in control visualization'? Does it have to do with kibana cofiguration?

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Run past timeout" in control field settings to list all the available values.

[image]